# How to set attributes of parallelAxis?

Tags: r, echarts4r

I just started to use `echarts4r`. When I was drawing a parallel coordinate system, I wanted to set the attributes of each dim, such as the maximum value, the minimum value, logbase and so on, but I didn't know how to implement them. I think it can be realized by the following methods：

```
df <- data.frame(
price = rnorm(5, 10),
amount = rnorm(5, 15),
letter = LETTERS[1:5]
)

p1 <- df |>
e_charts() |>
e_parallel(price, amount, letter, opts = list(smooth = TRUE))

p1$x$opts$parallelAxis[[1]]$max=30
p1$x$opts$parallelAxis[[2]]$min=15
```

But is there any other convenient method?